# Closed subspaces and operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{H}_1$ be closed subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that  $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$. Consider $\mathcal{H}_2:=T\mathcal{H}_1$. Is $T^*\mathcal{H}_2 \subset \mathcal{H}_1$?

Comment: I think it is false

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Would y give me a counterexample?

Comment: For example if $T$ is self-adjoint  than your question is $T^2 H_1 \subset H_1$ and in general is not true. In a finite dimensional case you can consider  a matrix $A$ such that $A^*=A$ and H_1=<v> where v is not an eighenvalue of $A$. Than is not possible that $A^*A H_1\subset H_1$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Consider $T : \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ given by the matrix $ \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}$. We have $T^* = T$.

Then $T (\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}) = \operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}$, but $$T(\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}) = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\} \not\subseteq \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}$$

Answer (score 0):

In general is not true. For example you can consider $T$ self-adjoint operator and $H_1=\langle v \rangle$ where $v\neq 0$ is not an eighenvector of $T^2$ ($H_1$ is closed because every finite dimensional subspace of an Hilbert  Space is closed).

In this way it is not possible that $T^*T H_1\subset H_1$ because if $T^2( \lambda v)$ is in $H_1$,with $\lambda\neq 0$,  than there exists $\mu$ such that $T^2(\lambda v)=\mu v$ and so

$T^2(v)=\frac{\mu}{\lambda}v$

and it is a contraddiction.